# Слогоделение, открытые и закрытые слоги

Tags: языкознание

Скажите, пожалуйста, являются ли слоги, заканчивающиеся на слогообразующий сонорный, открытыми?

Answer (score 1):

Открытым называется слог, который заканчивается слогообразующим звуком. В русском языке слогообразующими звуками являются гласные, поэтому обычно русские слова состоят из стольких слогов, сколько в них содержится гласных. Слог может заканчиваться на сонорный, но сам сонорный при этом не будет являться слогообразующим.
Если же речь идет о других языках, то, например, в чешском, сонорные могут быть слогообразующими. Но будут ли такие слоги открытыми - вопрос к специалистам по чешкому языку.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос некорректно поставлен.
Во-первых, в русском языке (да и в любом другом наверное) не может быть слогов, заканчивающихся на **слогообразующий** сонорный. Если звук слогообразующий, то он этот слог и порождает, а не заканчивает предыдущий, который и может быть открытым или закрытым. А во-вторых, в русском языке произношение любых согласных (в т.ч. сонорных) как слогообразующих не является орфоэпической нормой. Отдельные слова (мысль, театр) можно произносить с дополнительным слогом и без (тятыр-тятр, мысыль-мысль и т.д). Такой дополнительный слог всегда является закрытым т.к. протетический гласный возникает перед сонорным, но этот факт бессодержателен для грамматики или орфоэпии. А вот предыдущий слог, который при обычном произношении на такой сонорный бы заканчивался, может быть открытым или закрытым - в каждом конкретном случае надо разбираться отдельно.